# why swiper swiping on mobiles not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

have been trying to fix it, but can't find any solution for this problem on internet. i have this code:

```
       modules: [Navigation], 

       observer: true, 

       observeParents: true, 

       slidesPerView: 2, 

       spaceBetween: 8, 

       speed: 1000, 

  

       // navigation 

       navigation: { 

         prevEl: '.articles-mainpage .navigation__button_prev', 

         nextEl: '.articles-mainpage .navigation__button_next', 

       }, 

  

       // breakpoints 

       breakpoints: { 

         768: { 

           slidesPerView: 4, 

           spaceBetween: 30, 

         }, 

       },
```

...and base swiper CSS styling, but on mobiles it just doesn't swipe.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Also you can use this as reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/kv3dyt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.